# How to resolve this type of error "show is not a member "

Tags: apache-spark

```
scala> us.show
<console>:32: error: value show is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, String)]
              us.show
```

Comment: Please share more details of the problem. What language you use, when and how you get this error message, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, String)]` dosen't have a method `show()`

You have to change to dataframe as

```
import spark.implicits._

us.toDF().show()

us.toDF("id", "name").show //You can provide the column name here
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Answer (score 1):

RDD does not have show as method. Either you can convert rdd into data frame or into data set.

```
import spark.implicits._

assuming spark is your spark session.
```

You can use take method  in RDD

```
 
rdd.take(10).foreach(println)
here it will take 10 records from rdd and will print the result.
```